# How do you know what line contains a SCSS error when using @import in rails application manifest?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I am using Rails 4, sass-rails 4.0.2 and my application.css.scss file looks like:

```
@import 'foundation_and_overrides';
@import "font-awesome";
@import "vendors/*";
@import "layout";
@import "modules/*";
```

However, I am getting an undefined mixin error as follows:

```
Undefined mixin 'box-shadow'.
(in C:/Rails/austin_residence/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:4)
```

The problem is I do not know how to debug this since the error is reporting css lines from the application manifest file instead of the actual @import file containing the error. How do people deal with this?

Comment: Do you have `config.assets.debug = true` in your `config/environments/development.rb`? That configuration can help.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I do have it enabled and that worked when I used Sprockets directives. However, I'm not sure that option is relevant when using @imports as it still seems to concatenate the files

Comment: Try to add `config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`, then open the page on browser, it might raise the error and show where it is.

Comment: Even if you don't know a specific line number, the error clearly states that it can't find this 'box-shadow' mixin, so that may be the best place to start. Can you show the line of code where the box-shadow mixin is being called? If you're trying to use the compass box-shadow mixin (http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/box_shadow/), you have to import compass as well.

Answer (score 3):

Start commenting out the @imports in your application file.  When you don't see the error anymore, its probably in the file you stopped importing.